# Figures (pdf) do not contain any text in the final document

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, matlab

I am creating some plots in Matlab and saving them as pdf files. When I include these pdf files in latex (i am using MikTex and pdflatex) using `\includegraphics`, all text from plots (legends, xlabel, etc) does not show up in the final document. The exported pdf from matlab contain the text.

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how can I fix it ?

Edit (geometrikal):

Here is an example of a file with the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8184720/recon_rmse.pdf

I am using texstudio, with the buit in viewer (dvipng) and building with pdflatex. In the viewer it shows:

[image]

In Adobe reader it shows:

[image]

There are no errors or warnings in pdfTex about missing fonts.

Comment: Can you make one of the figures available for download? An example code that reproduces the problem would also be useful.

Comment: Without more information we can only guess. Are there any messages in the log file of the pdfTeX run that might shed some light on what's going wrong?

Comment: another guess -- the fonts used for the text in the figures are not embedded, and you don't have them available otherwise.  ordinarily, these would be replaced, but that may be suppressed.  check the log file, as already suggested.